# Create instance of a child class in an abstract base class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract

I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same as the code above in C++.
The idea is to return an instance of a child object in the base class.

```
public class A
{
    private B b;

    public A()
    {
        b = B.GetDefaultB();
    }

    public A(B _b)
    {
        b = _b;
    }
}

public abstract class B
{
    public static B GetDefaultB()
    {
        return new C();
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public C()
    {

    }
}
```

I tried to do something

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

A::A(){}
A::~A(){}

class B
{
public:
    B();
    static B* GetDefaultB();
    virtual ~B() = 0;
};

B::B(){}
B* B::GetDefaultB()
{
    return new C();
}
B::~B(){}

class C : public B
{
public:
    C();
    ~C();
};

C::C(){}
C::~C(){}
```

But I think there is a loop in the includes.
What should I do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder your class declarations and method definitions:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    static B* GetDefaultB();
    virtual ~B() = 0;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C();
    ~C();
};

A::A(){}
A::~A(){}

B::B(){}
B* B::GetDefaultB()
{
    return new C();
}

C::C(){}
C::~C(){}
```